# Why are two strings with same bytes and encoding not identical in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, ruby-1.9

In Ruby 1.9.2, I found a way to make two strings that have the same bytes, same encoding, and are equal, but they have a different `length` and different characters returned by `[]`.

Is this a bug?  If it is not a bug, then I'd like to fully understand it.  What kind of information is stored inside Ruby 1.9.2 String objects that allows these two strings to behave differently?

Below is the code that reproduces this behavior. The comments that start with `#=>` show you what output I am getting from this script, and the parenthetical words tell you my judgment of that output.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.9
# coding: utf-8
string1 = "\xC2\xA2"       # A well-behaved string with one character (¢)
string2 = "".concat(0xA2)  # A bizarre string very similar to string1.
p    string1.bytes.to_a    #=> [194, 162]  (good)
p    string2.bytes.to_a    #=> [194, 162]  (good)
puts string1.encoding.name #=> UTF-8  (good)
puts string2.encoding.name #=> UTF-8  (good)
puts string1 == string2    #=> true   (good)
puts string1.length        #=> 1      (good)
puts string2.length        #=> 2      (weird!)
p    string1[0]            #=> "¢"    (good)
p    string2[0]            #=> "\xC2" (weird!)
```

I am running Ubuntu and compiled Ruby from source.  My Ruby version is:

```
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: `p    string2.bytes.to_a` show result `[194, 162]` ?? That should not be!

Comment: Actually, Zabba, that is the expected result because 194,162 is the UTF-8 encoding of the cent character ¢ (codepoint 0xA2).  Apparently, if you pass an integer to concat, it will add one character with that value to your string.  See this table in Wikipedia aobut UTF-8.  They use the cent character as an example in the second row:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is Ruby's bug and fixed [r29848](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/repositories/revision/ruby-trunk?rev=29848).

Comment: It looks like you are the one who fixed it. Nice.

Comment: I downloaded and compiled Ruby r29852, ran the test code, and I confirm that this bug has been fixed!  `string1` and `string2` are now identical as far as I can tell.  Thank you, naruse!

Comment: That link is broken, but the original patch is visible at http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi?revision=29848&view=revision and http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/string.c?r1=29848&r2=29847&pathrev=29848

Answer (score 2):

Matz mentioned this question via Twitter:

http://twitter.com/matz_translator/status/6597021662187520

http://twitter.com/matz_translator/status/6597055132733440

"It's hard to determine as a bug but, it's not acceptable to leave it as is. I'd prefer to fix this issue."

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the string's encoding. Check out James Grey's [Shades of Gray: Ruby 1.9's String](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string) article on Unicode encoding.

---

Additional odd behavior:

```
# coding: utf-8

string1 = "\xC2\xA2"       
string2 = "".concat(0xA2)  
string3 = 0xC2.chr + 0xA2.chr

string1.bytes.to_a    # => [194, 162]
string2.bytes.to_a    # => [194, 162]
string3.bytes.to_a    # => [194, 162]

string1.encoding.name # => "UTF-8"
string2.encoding.name # => "UTF-8"
string3.encoding.name # => "ASCII-8BIT"

string1 == string2    # => true
string1 == string3    # => false
string2 == string3    # => true

string1.length        # => 1
string2.length        # => 2
string3.length        # => 2

string1[0]            # => "¢"
string2[0]            # => "\xC2"
string3[0]            # => "\xC2"
```

---

```
string3.unpack('C*') # => [194, 162]
string4 = string3.unpack('C*').pack('C*') # => "\xC2\xA2"
string4.encoding.name # => "ASCII-8BIT"
string4.force_encoding('UTF-8') # => "¢"

string3.force_encoding('UTF-8') # => "¢"
string3.encoding.name # => "UTF-8"
```

Comment: I found that article earlier tonight and read most of it but didn't find an answer.  Please note that both string1 and string2 have the same encoding, UTF-8.  Either I have found a bug in Ruby, or that article's description of Ruby 1.9 is incomplete.  The article claims "In Ruby 1.9 a String is now a collection of encoded data. That means it is both the raw bytes and the attached Encoding information about how to interpret those bytes."  But these two strings have the same bytes AND the same encoding, so why do they behave differently?  There must be some other important attribute of strings.

Comment: I lean toward it being a bug. Using `concat` with an integer is not intuitive to me. I'm messing with some additional tests to see what I can dig up.

Comment: I think it's a bug in concat.